# Android Marshmallow SQLiteOpenHelper onCreate / onUpgrade and file operations

Tags: android, permissions, android-contentprovider, sqliteopenhelper, android-6.0-marshmallow

currently my app is using a SQLiteOpenHelper to create or upgrade the underlying database. At the same time the app is creating some default database entries with file paths to images which are created in the following step (onCreate) or updating/migrating filepaths (and therefore moving images on external storage to a new location).

Until Android M everything was ok, because all necessary permissions were available. Now with M and targetApi = 23 my app has no longer the permission.

This shows that my solution was never a good one ;)

Whats the best way to do onCreate-Default-Operations or onUpgrade-Migrations which need permissions? Anyone who has the same or a similar problem?

regards,
Thomas

Comment: Under what circumstances would your `ContentProvider` be used before you had a chance to ask the user for permission? Admittedly, there's still the chance that the user later revokes the permission, but you would handle that the same way that you would handle other catastrophic problems, like out-of-disk-space errors.

Comment: Oh, I was wrong. I have a SQLiteOpenHelper with onCreate/onUpgrade in my ContentProvider. This is what I meant. Need to update my question.

Comment: My current thought is to extract all non-database-operations from SQLiteOpenHelper and run this in my first activity. But then I need to be careful to synchronize it to my database upgrades.